# How to run multiple mongoose queries at once and generate json respnose using expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-web-server

In this code I'm trying to get object counts from two different documents and send one json response with results from both quires. but unfortunately response of this code segment is always -1 it won't get updated with query results.

```
  router.get('/stats', function (req, res, next) {
  let cateCount = -1;
  let userCount = -1;
    Category.find({}).then(function(item){
    cateCount = item.length;
    });
    Register.find({}).then(function(item){
      userCount = item.length;
    });

  res.json({
    "categories": 
      cateCount,
    "users":
    userCount
  });
```

response :

```
{"categories":-1,"users":-1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to count documents use : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.count

and  **async-await** this way :

```
 router.get('/stats',async function (req, res, next) {
  let cateCount = -1;
  let userCount = -1;
    cateCount = await Category.count({});
    userCount = await Register.count({});
    res.json({
      categories:cateCount,
      users:userCount
   });
});
```

Comment: i modified your code snippet little bit to return item.length like before. it gives me a warning message saying "collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use Collection.countDocuments or Collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead"

Answer (score 0):

You can chain you calls, to wait for the callback before returning your response.
Here is one possible solution:

```
router.get('/stats', function (req, res, next) {
  let cateCount = -1;
  let userCount = -1;
    Category.find({}).then(function(item){
    cateCount = item.length;
        Register.find({}).then(function(item){
             userCount = item.length;
             res.json({
                "categories": cateCount,
                "users": userCount });
        });
  });
```

Comment: thank you for the answer what is the advantage of using this method instead of await (like above answer)

Comment: There is no advantage, is onlly another way to solve the problem. Maybe some advantage could be if you are not using a nodejs version that does not natively support `async/await` sintax you can use the callback pattern.

Comment: thnks for the explanation